# AutoMapper conditional Guid mapping causing exception

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following mapping:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<StructureDTO, Structure>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.ParentId, 
     opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ParentStructureId != Guid.Empty ? src.ParentStructureId : (Guid?)null)))

dest.ParentId is nullable Guid  
src.ParentStructureId is Guid
```

I get the following exception:

An exception of type `'System.InvalidOperationException'` occurred in `System.Core.dll` but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The operands for operator `'NotEqual'` do not match the parameters of method `'op_Inequality'`.

Is this because I'm trying to map two different types? I'm at a loss here.

Automapper version is 5.0.2

Comment: This is probably an AutoMapper bug, can you open a GitHub issue? Also this issue looks similar to ones fixed in 5.1.1.

Comment: @JimmyBogard Sure thing, want me to try updating before I open an issue?

Comment: Yeah that'd be my first question on the GH issue :)

Comment: Above code works with 5.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a method which does the work for you, then use the method in the `ForMember` method:

```
private Guid? Transform(StructureDTO src) {
    return src.ParentStructureId != Guid.Empty ? src.ParentStructureId : (Guid?) null;
}
```

then do your mapping this way:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<StructureDTO, Structure>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ParentId,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Transform(src))));
```

This is an error of AutoMapper's expression building logic, it tries to convert your lambda into a `.NET expression tree`, to bypass this we fore it to make a `MethodCallExpression`. This calls your new method directly without converting it into expressions.